# Colouring in my renders and Material Preview Mode has changed

Tags: rendering, color

I'm quite new to Blender but have been trying to render a design for a keyboard. I was able to produce something like:

[image]

note, the blues and the grey of the floor. This was rendered using the menu (ie. `render>render image (f12)`). However, as I was updating my objects, something must have happened that has changed the colour of everything in the renders. Now, everything is coloured like:

[image]

Note, the blues and greys are now totally different, and the lighting seems to have changed. I don't believe the properties of the objects have changed, and the actual hex codes of the colours are definitely the same. The problem persists even if I render through `Z render` and even when I access Material Preview via `Z` as well. If I copy everything into a different file, everything reverts back to the original, correct, colour scheme.

I don't even know where to begin trying to debug this. Can anyone please help me?

A commenter suggested I share the `.blend` file - it can be located [here](http://we.tl/t-rqEHH7tHio)

Comment: It's hard to tell. Are the images screenshots from the viewport or render outputs? Which shading mode is active (key Z)?

Comment: These are from render>render image (f12). However, there is a similar effect from going either Z Rendered or Z Material Preview

Comment: if you provide your blend file - we can check it out

Comment: thats very generous, its at https://we.tl/t-rqEHH7tHio - I feel I should note, that I'm quite new to this, so I'm sure I've got a lot to learn and I can see myself what I've done is a little messy.. ha.. Its weird as the colour (while it is wrong) is consistent throughout all of this .blend file. If you transfer an object out though it reverts to its "true" colour..

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I managed to change a color management setting was incorrect.

I fixed this by setting `Scene Properties > Color Management > Display Device` to sRGB